# Start youtube video from chrome extension background script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to play youtube video from chrome extension's background script as below, but it does not seem to work:

`chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,{code:"var player = document.getElementById('movie_player'); if(player.getPlayerState()!=1){player.playVideo();}" } );`

Comment: Does it throw any errors?

Comment: No. Just does not seem to have any effect.